# has_many associations table confusing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many, has-many-through

My goal here is to print list of users from specified city and category with their names, address and club name.Name and address display correctly but when i add club name,says `undefined method memberships for #<Enumerator:0xa5509b0>`.I know this is because Club is in different model ,So the question is how do i access club name?I am really shallow in complex has_many realtionships.Can anybody make necesary corrections please,This is how far i got.Thank you in advance

MODELS

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships 
  has_many : clubs,:through =>:memberships
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :city
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users 
  has_many :memberships 
  has_many : users ,:through =>:memberships
  belongs_to :city
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :club
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clubs 
  has_many :users  
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

CONTROLLER

```
  @users=User.where("category_id =? AND   city_id=?",Category.find(2),session[:city_id])
  @user=@users.collect
  @club=@user.memberships #this gives undefined method membership
```

VIEW

```
    <% @user.each do |user| %>
   <%= user.username %>
   <%= user.address %>
   <%= @club.name %> #attribute name is in the club model not membership
   <%end%>
```

ROUTE

```
       devise_for :users
      resources :city,:club,:category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below returns an array instead of what you are expecting, i.e. User object.

```
@user=@users.collect
```

If users shown in the view belong to different clubs you should access them directly in the view. You can eager load the clubs if needed.

**In your controller**

```
@users=User.where(:category_id => Category.find(2), :city_id=>session[:city_id]).
  include(:clubs)
```

**In your view**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.username %>
  <%= user.address %>
  <% user.clubs.each do |club| %>
    <%= club.name %>
  <%end%>  
<%end%>
```

Comment: I just realized you created that vote_fu gem ,i had some questions for you,i am using that gem in my app.

Comment: @katie: Post your query as a regular SO question.

Comment: i did post few days ago,but no one answered,seems not so many people have used it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error in Club class. You cant have 2 relations with the same name. Second one will override first.

```
has_many : users ,:through =>:memberships
```

should be

```
has_many :members, :through =>:memberships, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
```

The search should be:

```
@users = User.where(:category_id => 2, :city_id => 3).include(:clubs)
```

Or whatever it values you want to search by.The view is:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.username %>
  <%= user.address %>
  <%= user.club.name %> #attribute name is in the club model not membership
<%end%>
```

Your routes are fine.